# Identifying a wall socket with 8 small, 2 larger holes in trapezoid/star configuration

Tags: connector, socket

What kind of connector is this?

- Country: Germany
- Location: University Building (Department of Computer Science)
- The logo in the middle rather looks like an "h"
- 6 smaller holes form a trapezoid
- 2 of the smaller holes are horizontally arranged in the middle
- The 2 large holes are horizontally arranged at the bottom

[image: 8 smaller holes, 2 larger holes]

It is located in a wall panel where also power outlets and telephone and ethernet sockets are located.

Comment: I don't know but it's cute.

Comment: Are you sure its a connector and not just a vent?

Comment: Which country? Old building / newer building? Is the building used for anything with special equipment (e.g. medical use)? I'm guessing that the answer will come from someone who recognizes it straight away but more information never hurts.

Comment: Has anyone sacrificed a goat nearby?  If so it's a portal to the netherworld.  Either that or it might be an electric shaver socket.

Comment: A buzzer? if you remove the 2 screws what's behind the plate?

Comment: I notice it's 2+8, so perhaps power and a byte? Are all the holes wired behind the plate? Google image search 'by image' comes up with nothing. You could try an image search on that little 'b' logo in the middle.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a manufacturer + part number for this socket (or the corresponding plug)? Or do you want to know what kind of device is supposed to be plugged in this? Are you asking for the pinout?

Comment: It looks like Patrick Starfish from spongebob.

Comment: It's to connect your http://thelaundryfiles.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Grids

Comment: I added some more information. I did not remove the screws and don't know how it's wired. Maybe I can find out when the building was built.

Comment: Since it's located in the computer science lab, why don't you ask a professor?

Comment: The connector Manufacturer is definitely the former Hirschmann (now part of Belden). I cannot find anything about this connector type, but it looks like an old analoge phone connector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not able to comment, so I will leave extra information here, in case it proves useful to you.

The connector is a [Hirschmann MEDU1000 ref.973078-135](http://www.beckwithelectronics.com/hirschmn/m1000.htm) from the ME series.

It is used for control signals.

According with product description, it can be used for connecting telecommunications, measurement systems and laboratory equipment.

Sorry, but I don't know what specific devices might require this connection.

Comment: No need for a comment, you have the correct answer.  I found a [datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/CA6GS-Hirschmann-datasheet-505086.pdf) that gives more information about the MEDU 1000 - plus a lot more connectors.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to find someone who knows what kind of device used to be plugged into this socket.